# Is a realization of Page Object Model an example of encapsulation in Java?

Tags: java, oop, testing

Is a realization of POM an example of encapsulation? Are all imported libraries, code builders (maven/gradel/..) and all used code in the project, which realization is based behind "closed doors", examples of encapsulation?

Comment: Sorry, I mean a realization of Page Object Model (one of test automation patterns)

Comment: Put that fact into both the title and body of your Question, not a Comment. And assign a tag, if one exists.

Comment: Feel free to ask any question. If you feel that my reply is helpful, then you can upvote or mark my reply as an answer to simplify the future search of other users. [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/309682)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say whether Page Object Model is an example of encapsulation. However, as [wiki says about encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)):

> In object-oriented programming (OOP), encapsulation refers to the
> bundling of data with the methods that operate on that data, or the
> **restricting of direct access to some of an object's components**. Encapsulation is used **to hide the values or state of a structured
> data object inside a class**, preventing direct access to them by
> clients in a way that could expose hidden implementation details or
> violate state invariance maintained by the methods.

So if `Page Object Model` hides the values or state from direct access by other users, then it can be said that it is an exmaple of encapsulation.

One of the ways to achieve encapsulation is to use `setter` and `getter` methods and access modifiers. Let me show an example:

```
public class EncapsulatedPerson
{
    private string name;

    public string GetName() 
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void SetName(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and `Person` without encapsulation. Any user of class `NotEncapsulatedPerson` can edit `name`:

```
public class NotEncapsulatedPerson
{
    public string name;
}
```